# Literal string assignment paradox

Tags: c++11

Why does assigning literal strings to mutable character arrays like

```
char * p = "Hello World!\n";
```

result in a warning while passing literal string to a function argument like

```
void function foo(char* p) {
  //do stuff
}

int main() {
  foo("Hello World!\n");
}
```

does not result in a warning

I come from ruby land where all of this was done for me lol its a bold new world for me thanks for helping me understand

Comment: I would venture to guess, "Because your compiler is a piece of junk."

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, [g++ as old as 4.6 warns about this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3710eb3acfbf532c) just fine. Maybe they removed the warning in 4.8.1?

Comment: If you use `std::string`, you can avoid any of these issues.

Comment: I like to understand what's going on under the hood so to speak but yah most defiantly plan on leaning all the libraries available

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c728ec868bd03477), both clang and gcc produce a warning even with no additional flags turned on.

Comment: I'm using
g++ -std=c++11 char_counter.cpp -o char_count

Comment: Here is a gist of the actual program that doesn't throw an error https://gist.github.com/cannapages/11298577

Comment: Ahh nm thank you every one. I was assigning a literal string to a mutable object and passing that.

Comment: That program doesn't pass a string literal to a function. It doesn't warn about a problem because there's no problem to warn about. `foo` is in fact a mutable char array. What again is this example supposed to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile your program, I get the warning two times which is what I expect. The pointer assignment and the direct function call with string literal gives:

```
 warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

And actual this warnings should be treated as errors, because you are not able to change the content of what the pointer points to. If you try to modify the content in foo() you run

```
void foo(char* p)
{
  p[0]='n';
}
```

results into an exception which is what we expect!

The problem is not the function foo but the init to a const array.

If you change your code to:

```
void foo(char* p) {
    p[0]='n';
}   

int main() {
    char * from = "Hello World!\n";
    char * to = new char[100]; // enough space to put the string here
    strcpy( to, from );
    foo( to );
    foo( from );
    cout << to << endl;
 }
```

and run this in a debugger, your program crash in line `foo( from );`

What you should always do:

If your function will not modify the content of that what the pointer points to, make the `pointer` to a `const pointer`.

If your program have to modify the content of that what the pointer points to, you have to use memory which you can write on.

A simple change can do the job:

```
int main() {
    char from[]= "Hello World!\n";   
    //char* from= "Hello World!\n";
    foo( from );
    cout << from << endl;
}
```

The difference here is:

`from` is now an array on the stack, local to your function main. And you can modify your own array inside the function foo().

My hint: if you see a warning of passing a const value to a non const pointer, treat this always as error and not only as a warning. This is only a warning while tons of old code will not compile anymore. But remember: A write access to a const value is always undefined behavior and normally a crash.

Comment: That used to be legal C and it had to be allowed for backward compatibility.